# Assembler debug trying to print quotient and remainder

Tags: assembly

I am attempting to create a program through DOSBOX (program name is mod.com) and I'm having trouble printing out my quotient and remainder of 91 x 13 mod 23.

```
mov cl, 91
mov bl, 13
mul bl
mov al, 23
mod al
mov dl,al
mov ah,2
int 21
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `mul`? It doesn't work the way you think. There is no `mod` instruction. You'll need to use `div` (see the documentation for use). Finally, to print, you will need to convert your result to ASCII to make it printable.

Comment: I typed my thoughts instead of what I had written down.  I did have the div instead of the mod.

Comment: You need to edit your question (click the "edit" link below the question) and update to match your code. Also, see my other comments about other issues with your code.

Comment: To print a number you need to convert it to string, then you print the string. Here is function `number2string` to do the job : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30110083/3298930 .

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by just weeding out the errors first:

- To use `mul bl`, first put the number 91 in the `AL` register (not `CL`).
- To obtain quotient and remainder, use the `div bl` instruction (there's no "mod") with the number 23 in the `BL` register.
- To output with DOS use hexadecimal 21h instead of decimal 21.

Like so:

```
mov  al, 91
mov  bl, 13
mul  bl       ;product in AX
mov  bl, 23
div  bl       ;quotient in AL, remainder in AH
mov  dl, al
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
```

---

This code is correct but it won't show anything useful because the byte in the `DL` register doesn't represent a character yet. You need to convert it.

The quotient is in `AL` and has the value 51. This will lead to outputting 2 characters.
This is my version to display it:

```
aam           ;divides AL by 10, leaves 5 in AH and 1 in AL
add  ax, "00" ;converts to characters: "5" in AH and "1" in AL
mov  dx, ax   ;"5" in DH and "1" in DL
xchg dl, dh   ;"1" in DH and "5" in DL  We need to output "5" first!
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
mov  dl, dh   ;Secondly we output "1"
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
```

To additionally output the remainder use a similar code, but remember that without precautions its value (in `AH`) by now will be lost!
So temporarilly save it on the stack:

```
push ax
...           ;The code above
pop  ax
mov  al, ah   ;Now the remainder is back again
...           ;The code above
```